# How do you switch off a identity insert function in Microsoft SQL management studo?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can you switch a set identity insert off? eg: `[SET Identity_Insert tblSuppliers ON]`. Can this be switched off in Microsoft SQL Server Management studio, if so how do you switch it off?

Comment: IF you're asking for the command to turn this off in SQL Server Management Studio, why is this tagged for C#?

Comment: The [manual](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259221(v=sql.80).aspx) is always a good place to check.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is not a good fit for our site for a few reasons. Consider reading [ask]. Especially since you know that to turn it on, you enter `SET Identity_Insert tblSuppliers ON`, you might have saved yourself some time by trying Nick's `SET Identity_Insert tblSuppliers OFF` before asking.

Answer (score 3):

`SET Identity_Insert tblSuppliers OFF`